# Appendchild() with two inputs, and removing latest post

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input, textarea (name + comment) and Submit button. Onclick should post text from input and textarea. I use appendchild(), but need to call textarea.
1. How should I do it?
2. Button "Delete" remove all post, but I need delete just the last one. So how it is possible?
Thank you for any tips.

There is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function append(form) {
        if (form.input.value) {
            var newItem = document.createElement("div");
            newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(form.input.value));
            document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(newItem);
        }
    }

    function restore() {
        var oneChild;
        var mainObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        while (mainObj.childNodes.length > 0) {
            oneChild = mainObj.lastChild;
            mainObj.removeChild(oneChild);
        }
    }
</script>
<form>Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <br />Comment:
    <br>
    <textarea type="text" name="textarea"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="append(this.form)" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="restore()" />
</form>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You could use a jsfiddle...

Comment: `but I need delete just the last one`. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is because you are saying while there are posts delete last one.

Put just this code in `restore`. It will remove last child once.

```
function restore() {
    var oneChild;
    var mainObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    oneChild = mainObj.lastChild;
    mainObj.removeChild(oneChild);
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure there is a lastChild before trying to remove it?  ie, replace OP's `while` with an `if`

Answer (score 0):

To solve your append issue:

```
function append(form) {
  if (form.input.value) {  
    var newItem = document.createElement("div");
    newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(form.input.value));
    //add a line break and the text from textarea
    newItem.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(form.textarea.value));
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(newItem);
  }
}
```

If you want to delete the last item only, you have to convert the `while` loop to an `if` condition:

```
function restore() {
  var oneChild;
  var mainObj = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  if (mainObj.childNodes.length > 0) {
    oneChild = mainObj.lastChild;
    mainObj.removeChild(oneChild);
  }
}
```